# Ctrl + Tab to switch between the Graph Editor and Dopesheet no longer work (since Blender 3.2)

Tags: animation

This has been bugging me for awhile and I've even tried starting up Blender's default settings, to no avail. Ctrl + Tab in the dopesheet or graph editor no longer switches between them. Instead, it throws this error:

Python: TypeError: could not find function execute in WM_OT_context_set_enum to execute callback

When I go into the hotkey preferences for the graph editor it looks like this:

[image]

Is anyone else having this issue?  How do I fix this? Any help would be very much appreciated!!
Cheers and stay safe,

Allen Grippin

Comment: Hello, that's weird, it works fine for me in 3.3 and 3.4, and your preferences panel seems correct

Answer (score 2):

the addon zen sets seems to be the offender. Face2Face addon is annoying because it creates a scene action in the Blender file, but functionality in the graph editor/dope sheet returns after disabling Zen Sets.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the problem was with old version of Zen Sets. But it is fixed in the latest version 2.1.3. So, update please to the latest Zen Sets